# SQL Server 2005 SP4 & VS 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

We have SQL Server 2005 SP1 currently and VS 2005. We're planning on installing SP4 for Sql Server 2005.

Question: Are there any specific requirements for this install or known negative effects that we should know about?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried it on a VM?

Comment: @p.campbell: No.

Comment: How about save some time, headache, and frustration, and do the work/testing in a VM? How can you rely on answers on the internet and not test anything?

Comment: Of course we will test first. Talking about saving time, though, how about first finding out if we can install it in the first place - do I first need to have previous SPs? Will it have an effect on VS's ability to connect to SQL? I couldn't find anything of value on the web, so I thought I'd see if anyone here has any info that can help.

Answer (score 1):

You should "smoke test" in a testing environment whenever possible but, in general, SQL Server service packs have not been the cause of great difficulties in my experience (especially not with SQL Server 2005).

In response to your comment: SQL Service Service Packs are not "additive"-- that is you can install Service Pack 4 over any existing prior version without needing to load "prerequisites".